# Django Templates — passing value of a variable in a template to templatetags filter

Tags: django, templates, django-templates, tags

name class an id, a first & a last attributes

In my view.py, I fetch a name object from the database and pass it into the index.html template.

In my `templagetags/my_tags.py`, I have a filter `my_private_tag(value, arg)` that takes value and an arg. It appends the arg to the value and returns the result.

```
def my_private_tag(value, arg):
  return value + ' ' + arg
```

In my index.html tag I need to do the following.

```
{% if name %}

  # to display 
  # John says hello
  {{name.first | my_private_tag:"says hello"}

  # Johns student id = id_value
  {{name.first | my_private_tag:"????????"}

  # Johns student id = id_value, lastname = lastname_value
  {{name.first | my_private_tag:"????????"}

{% endif %}
```

Where:

```
id_value = name.id & lastname_value = name.last
```

Please fill in the ???????? if you can.

Comment: I edited my example and it should work now. {{name.first|my_private_tag:name.id}}

Answer (score 8):

Instead of implementing your own filter for this. Why not do it this way:

```
{{name.first }} says hello
{{name.first }}'s student id = {{ name.id }}
```

It is much more readable. And this is how you are supposed to use templates anyway.

If you still want to use a custom filter for this, you can probably pass the variable like this:

```
{{name.first|my_private_tag:name.id}}
```

Comment: Thanks Nadia,

Well, I put a simple example to figure out how to do this.
The real filter will do more stuff on the input.
And for your information, this just doesn't work. {{name.first | my_private_tag:name.id}}. Thanks.

Comment: I removed the spaces between the filter and the arguments. Apparently django doesn't like that. The new example worked for me.

Comment: Thanks Nadia, Do you know how to make this work:
{{name.first|my_private_tag:studend_id=name.id}}. Something like named argument.

Answer (score 0):

If the filter only gets two strings, it won't have access to the original name object, so there's no way to get the ID.

I think you're headed the wrong direction by wanting to do this with a filter when you can use the existing tags to get the result you want. But, for the sake of argument, let's say that you could get

```
Johns student id = 47, lastname = Doe
```

from the filter. How would you do it? First, you'd have to pass the name object to the filter

```
{{name|my_private_tag:"??????"}}
```

The code for the filter then becomes

```
return name.first_name + "s student id = " + name.id + ", lastname = " + name.last_name
```

Notice that you're not using the argument. If you wanted your filter to return different things depending on the argument, then add conditional logic and off you go.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a value that consists solely of a combination of model field values dictated by the business logic, a templatetag is not the right way to go.

Instead, this should be a property of the model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(...)
    lastname = models.CharField(...)

    @property
    def student_id(self):
        return '{}{}'.format(self.id, self.lastname)
```

You can use this property everywhere, not only in your templates but also in views, exports, the Admin UI etc. Which you probably need seeing that `student_id` sounds like a rather important attribute.

In the template:

```
{% if student %}

  # to display 
  # John says hello
  {{ student.firstname }} says hello

  # John's student id
  Student ID: {{ student.student_id }}

{% endif %}
```

Templatetags should be created for more generic functionality and functionality that depends on the current request and not for something you will ever only apply to one specific model in a specific context. And, most importantly, they are not meant for functionality that is not restricted to templates.